Making Random Integer's in C# within parameters
Trying to make unity generate random pipes that come across the screen in a unique position within a set parameters. I have tried playing around with it but can't make it work. I was wondering if any of you would be able to help find a fix.
Tried using a Next() method to create a random integer but I couldn't get it to work. I am very new to C# and unity so any help would be appreciated.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEngine.RuleTile.TilingRuleOutput;
using Random = Unity.Mathematics.Random;

public class PipeSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject pipe;
    public float spawnRate = 2;
    private float timer = 0;
    public float heightoffset = 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SpawnPipe();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timer < spawnRate)
        {
            timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else 
        {
            SpawnPipe();
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
    void SpawnPipe()
    {
        float lowestPoint = transform.position.y - heightoffset;
        float heighistpoint = transform.position.y + heightoffset;

        Instantiate(pipe, new Vector3(transform.position.x, new Random(lowestPoint, heighistpoint), 0), transform.rotation);
    }
      

}


FWIW, the word is highest, not heighist. Spelling it correctly saves two keystrokes every time it's used. :-)

Your image failed to upload, can you try again?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-8.0 You don't use Random(low, high). You need to make a Random object, then call the methods on it to create random values.

Have you tried reading the documentation? Keep in mind that Unity has a different Random than the one built into the base class library.

Does this answer your question? Random Numbers in Unity3D?

To generate a random integer in Unity, use UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max + 1). Note that the second argument, the maximum, is exclusive, so it should be 1 more than the maximum value that you want. This is to make it easier to work with arrays.
For example, if you want to pick a random number between 1 and 3 inclusive, you would use Random.Range(1, 4).
